# I am having an error in Json schema markup for Google indexing for SERP starts

Tags: json, schema

I am setting up schema for rating stars to show up on google search results, I got this json script, It does not have any error when I test the code snippet, But shows an error :

> Missing '}' or object member name.

```
<script type=application/ld+json>{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "image": "https://www.rmsdrill.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/RMS-Logo-header.png",
    "name": "Rms Drill",</p>
<p>    "telephone": "(800) 605-1608",
    "address" :{
      "@type": "PostalAddress",</p>
<p>      "addressLocality": "Dallas",
      "addressRegion": "TX",
      "postalCode": "75219",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    }
  },
  "reviewRating": {
    "@type": "Rating",
    "ratingValue": "4"
  },
  "name": "Working with Rober Strunks.",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Dr. Jason Kihle"
  },
  "reviewBody": "After just one season of working with Robert Strunks, it is absolutely clear that he is everything that you want in a professional marching band drill designer. In addition…",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "RMS Drill"
  }
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, use this: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
{  
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Review",
   "itemReviewed":{  
      "@type":"LocalBusiness",
      "image":"https://www.rmsdrill.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/RMS-Logo-header.png",
      "name":"Rms Drill",
      "telephone":"(800) 605-1608",
      "address":{  
         "@type":"PostalAddress",
         "addressLocality":"Dallas",
         "addressRegion":"TX",
         "postalCode":"75219",
         "addressCountry":"US"
      }
   },
   "reviewRating":{  
      "@type":"Rating",
      "ratingValue":"4"
   },
   "name":"Working with Rober Strunks.",
   "author":{  
      "@type":"Person",
      "name":"Dr. Jason Kihle"
   },
   "reviewBody":"After just one season of working with Robert Strunks, it is absolutely clear that he is everything that you want in a professional marching band drill designer. In addition…",
   "publisher":{  
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"RMS Drill"
   }
}
```